# First char of String, use as a condition... (Java, Android)

Tags: java, android

So I want to check if the First character of a String is a "!". This works great, but if I use it as a condition it's wrong everytime. Look at my example:

```
next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
            EditText num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number);
            String text = num.getText().toString();

            int len = text.length();

            String help = text;

            String first = String.valueOf(help.charAt(0));

            if (len == 7 && first == "!") {
                int value = text;
                //...
            } else {
                int value2 = text;
            }

        }
    });
```

Thanks...

Comment: Why even store it in a variable? Try this, `if (len == 7 && text.charAt(0) == '!') {`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't compare Strings with `==`, because it compares object references, and not the content of the strings. Use `first.equals("!")`.

Or better, don't transform your char into a String, and just use

```
char first = help.charAt(0);
if (len == 7 && first == '!')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `equals` for String,

`if (len == 7 && "!".equals(first)) {`

Answer (score 1):

You must use the String.equals() method for string equality

Answer (score 0):

to determine if two strings have the same content, you have to use the String.equals(String another string) method, not the "==" statement.

actually,I think you could do it better,why not simply use compare the char,not the string,by calling text.charAt(0)=='!'

Answer (score 0):

Some of these don't seem to work, at least not anymore in my version.  You can't compare strings and char directly. Instead, do this:

```
String string = "!Android";
if(string.charAt(0) == "!".charAt(0)){
  //Do what you want here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your code a little bit, it will work now

```
next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View view) {
        EditText num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number);
        String text = num.getText().toString();

        int len = text.length();

        //String help = text;

        //String first = String.valueOf(help.charAt(0));

        if (len == 7 && "!".equals(text.charAt(0))) {
            int value = text;
            //...
        } else {
            int value2 = text;
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna check from which letter your string start

```
    String name=txtname.getText().toString(); //get text from txt field
                  boolean s=name.startsWith("A");
                  if(s)
                  {
                      edtfield.setText("your name start with A" );
                      //set value of field

                  }
                  else
                  {
                      edtmessagebody.setText("not start with A");
                  }
```

[image: out put]